# I have want to create a new variable in my dataset based on observations that have specific letters in the Sample ID

Tags: r

I have data with sample ID's (B1T1,B2T1...) and i want to assign "Recovery" to all B1 and B2 samples, and assign "Acidic" to all B3 and B4 samples, but because the names are linked with Treatments (T1,T2 etc) I need a way to assign the new variable just based on part of the Sample ID.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would really help if you can provide a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for `separate` from tidyr:

```r
library(tidyr)
ID <- c("B1T1", "B1T2", "B2T1", "B3T1", "B4T1", "B4T2")
val <- rnorm(6)
df <- data.frame(ID = ID, val = val)

df
#>     ID        val
#> 1 B1T1  0.2990410
#> 2 B1T2 -0.1363163
#> 3 B2T1 -0.5500596
#> 4 B3T1  0.7734307
#> 5 B4T1 -0.7522459
#> 6 B4T2 -0.5597933

df %>%
  separate(ID, sep = 2, into = c("Group", "Treatment"))
#>   Group Treatment        val
#> 1    B1        T1  0.2990410
#> 2    B1        T2 -0.1363163
#> 3    B2        T1 -0.5500596
#> 4    B3        T1  0.7734307
#> 5    B4        T1 -0.7522459
#> 6    B4        T2 -0.5597933
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

From there, you can relabel your 'B' groups and treatments separately.